# JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /Dashboard/Dashboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Okay I am getting this error when clicking on tab in my ASP.NET MVC application. It is using jquery and bootstrap. This error is supposedly coming out of jquery-3.2.1.min.js.

My ASP.NET code is:

```
<div class="col">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li id="user-dash">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="@Url.Action("Dashboard", 
             "Dashboard")">Home</a>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

So when I click that tab there it ends up throwing this error. There are actually more tabs, but didn't copy them for brevity. So there appears to be something it doesn't like about the `@Url.Action("Dashboard", "Dashboard")` However, I have used this on different tabs and it worked just fine. I cannot for the life of me figure it out. If there is more info needed let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Bootstrap tabbed panes use the `href` as a CSS selector for the pane that is to be shown, you gave a url instead

Comment: Okay so just removing the `data-toggle="tab"` should make this work as expected. And it does. Thank you!